# How to show the following is isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory

How would I show that the groups $G = D_{n}$ and $H = \mathbb Z_{2n} $, where $n > 2$ is isomorphic?  $D_n$ is the dihedral group with $n$ being the order of the group. I tried testing if one was cyclic or abelian and the other was not, but that did not work. Can anyone please give me some suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean not isomorphic?

Comment: The order of $D_n$ is $2n$.

Comment: It should have worked: as soon as $n > 2$, $D_n$ isn't Abelian: just take a reflection and a "small" rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually already have the right idea: one of $D_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ is cyclic (and therefore also abelian), whereas the other is not cyclic (and even not abelian).

(If $|D_n|=n$ then the isomorphism already fails because then $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ has more elements than $D_n$, so I assume that $D_n$ is the dihedral group with $2n$ elements.)